# Counting Size of List, is it necessary to use free()?

Tags: c, list

I have a function that counts the size of a linked list.  I was getting a 'double free or corruption' compile error when the lines before return excluded `temp=NULL` and I would only `free(temp)`.  When I added `temp=NULL` before `free(temp)`, the code worked.

Was I getting a double free or corruption because the compiler freed `temp` and the node it was linked to?  Does `temp=NULL` resolve that?

Ultimately, is it necessary to use `free()` for a function this small?

```
typedef struct node{
    int a, b;
    struct node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct list{
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
}List;

int list_size(List *q){
    Node *temp;
    int i = 1;
    if(q->tail == NULL && q->head == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        temp = q->head;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
            ++i;
        }
        temp = NULL;
        free(temp);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `temp=NUL`L before `free(temp)` "works" because in that case your free boils down to `free(NULL)` which does nothing.

Comment: BTW why do you free the elements of the list when you just want to count the number of elements??

Comment: @MichaelWalz - I thought that it was necessary to free temp - but its clear now, `temp` wasn't allocated any memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't allocate any memory, so you don't need to free any memory. Any way, if you allocate memory you need to free it.

Memory that needs to be freed is memory that was dynamically allocated. Functions that dynamically allocate memory are listed in the documentation for free: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free

Answer (score 2):

As a correct programming technique, you should always `free()` the memory you allocated dynamically, no matter what amount of memory we are talking about. 
However, here you did not allocate any memory for temp. Thus, your problem was solved because you set temp to NULL and actually freed NULL, which does not affect your program.